# Removing <p> tag from an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array as `["<p>123</p>", "<p>124</p>", "<p>125</p>"]` and i want to remove the `<p>` tags as below.

```
[123, 124, 125]
```

I'm expecting it to be a dynamic function to handle the same using javascript. Please help me to resolve the same.

Comment: Have you tried using things like `.map()` or `.forEach()` ?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let output = ["<p>123</p>", "<p>124</p>", "<p>125</p>"].map(
             item => parseInt(item.replace("<p>", "").replace("</p>", "")));
 console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would either extract the numbers or replace the tags.

I added examples for both. And I added `parseInt`, because I assume you want to have integers in the end. If you want to have strings, just remove it.

Here is an example with replacing the tags:

```js
let data = ["<p>123</p>", "<p>124</p>", "<p>125</p>"]

let result = data.map(x => parseInt(x.replace(/<\/?p>/g, "")));
// Note: for any tags, you could use the regex /<\/?.+?>/g instead

console.log(result);
```

And another example extracting the numbers:

```js
let data = ["<p>123</p>", "<p>124</p>", "<p>125</p>"]

let result = data.map(x => parseInt(x.replace(/\D*(\d+)\D*/g, "$1")));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: OP may not want these values to be integers, but rather to remain as strings. As such, it might be worth noting `parseInt` as optional.

Answer (score 1):

Slicers

```js
const data = ["<p>123</p>", "<p>124</p>", "<p>125</p>"]

const result = data.map(x => parseInt(x.slice(3,x.length-3)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.replace()` with a regular expression to capture the `<p>` and `</p>` strings and remove them with the following regex:

```
/<\/?p>/g
```

[Regex test](https://regexr.com/54j9m)

```js
let data = [
  "<p>123</p>",
  "<p>124</p>",
  "<p>125</p>"
];

let result = data.map(el => el.replace(/<\/?p>/g, ""));

console.log(result);
```